# React Typescript : MuiAccordion OnChange event handler type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am new to typescript, need guidance on writing type for event handler.
I am using material ui Accordion in my component, and calling handler from container. So I need to specify the type of handleChange in my component interface.

Inside component :

```
<Accordion
        square
        expanded={expanded === 'panel1'}
        onChange={handleChange('panel1')}
>Content</Accordion>
```

Inside container:

```
   const handleChange = (panelName: string) => (event, isExpanded: boolean) =>  {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panelName : false)
  }
```

(JSX attribute) AccordionProps.onChange?: ((event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean) => void) | undefined

Error : Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean) => void) | undefined'.

Question: What should be specified as a Type for handleChange?

```
interface Props {
  expanded: string
  handleChange: ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working, after putting interface type as below,

```
interface Props {
  expanded: string | boolean
  handleChange: (
    panel: string,
  ) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, expanded: boolean) => void
}
```

Container call:

```
const handleChange = (panel: string) => (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>,
    isExpanded: boolean,
  ) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false)
  }
```

I was confused due to curried function, but I am not sure, using **Type - 'unknown'** is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleChange` is a function that returns a function that returns `void` (it just sets a component state).

Anyway, I guess that `Props.handleChange` is actually `Props.onChange` (if it is the Props of Accordion). Anyway, that props signature should be `(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean) => void` I guess (as the compiler tells you).

So something like this:

```js
interface Props {
    expanded: string;
    onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean): void;
    // or
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean) => void;
}
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, expanded: boolean) => void , Here I get typescript eslint error to avoid empty object literal. Thank you for replying to my question